# Repeating find with a loop in MongoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

This is the classic JavaScript closure vs. loop variable problem, but with a twist. There is a MongoDB collection containing archived tweets. I have to perform a find operation on it, searching for various search words. The words are in an array as strings, they have to be sought separately and all the results returned in a single JSON response.

The easiest way seems to be to run a for loop through the array an perform the MongoJS find() operation with each element. While this actually works and returns proper data, the loop variable still remains inaccessible within the callback function as it's always 4 - the last possible value for the loop, the index of the last element of the array.

I need to know the correct value which the loop variable had when the callback was invoked. Anyone has a good idea how to do this? Thanks.

```
  var searchwords = ['java', 'javascript', 'ruby', 'scala', 'python'];
  var json = new Array();

  for(t in searchwords) {

        var regexp = new RegExp('\\b'+searchwords[t]+'\\b', 'gi');
        coll.find({ 'timestamp_ms': { $gte: String(startdate) },
                    'timestamp_ms': { $ne: undefined },
                    'text': regexp
                  }, function(err, docs) {
                                          json.push({ 
                                                      'searchword': searchwords[t],
                                                      'tweets': docs.length
                                                    });
                                          console.log(t+' : '+docs.length);
                                        });

  }

  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
  res.end(JSON.stringify(json, null, ' '));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you can do is use this

```
var i = 0;
async.eachSeries(searchwords , function(word, cb){
    var regexp = new RegExp('\\b'+searchwords[t]+'\\b', 'gi');
    coll.find({ 'timestamp_ms': { $gte: String(startdate) },
                'timestamp_ms': { $ne: undefined },
                'text': regexp
              }, function(err, docs) {
                                      json.push({ 
                                                  'searchword':searchwords[t],
                                                  'tweets': docs.length
                                                });
                                      console.log(i+' : '+docs.length);
                                      i++;
                                      cb();
                                    });
})
```

its not a good idea to use foorloop for db calls as it will flush calls together and there will be problem when array is big.
this will give you correct index because next iteration is not called until cb() is called

Comment: Obviously I still have a lot to learn after spending just three hours with MongoDB. :) Thank you!